# Installing NuPIC on my ubuntu throughs system error

Tags: ubuntu, numpy

I am trying to install NuPIC on my ubuntu os and done with installing all packages. When I try to run setup.py it keeps giving me the following error:

```
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

This occurs when it is trying to install numpy, but the thing is that I have installed numpy successfully and dont know why it tries to install again. Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be useful for others. After dealing with lots of errors and not being able to address them. I ended up using a docker file from NuPIC which solved everything smoothly. The link to docker:

```
https://hub.docker.com/r/numenta/nupic/~/dockerfile/
```

And the command you need to run:

```
docker pull numenta/nupic
```

If you have docker up and running this will work like a charm. Read instructions about how to get docker up and running:

```
https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/
```

Cheers